React - Axios Call ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
I'm training on React to assess the work to replace our front end from ExtJS to React.
I downloaded a free React template, and managed to set up the login but when I try to make a simple get axios call to my API I get the error 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'.
I tried with our current front and the call is working, I tried as well in Postman and it's working.
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
        try {
            const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently();
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:10000/******/Currencies', {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
                }
            });
            setProducts(response.data.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    fetchProducts();
}, [getAccessTokenSilently]);

EDIT :
Code snippet from postman :
const axios = require("axios");

let config = {
  method: "get",
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  url: "localhost:10000****/Currencies",
  headers: { Authorization: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJS...." },
};
axios
  .request(config)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

While investigating, I noticed our current front end uses a node js server. After starting it, I now have a CORS error.
Here's the startup class of the Web API which is in .Net framework 4.8 :
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(new CorsOptions
        {
            PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
            {
                PolicyResolver = context =>
                    Task.FromResult(new CorsPolicy
                    {
                        AllowAnyMethod = true,
                        AllowAnyHeader = true,
                        Origins = { "http://localhost:10000", "http://localhost:3000" }, // Specify allowed origins
                        SupportsCredentials = true // Enables credentials for cross-origin requests
                    })
            }
        });

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("");
            }
            else
            {
                await next();
            }
        });

        var authorizedIPs = new HashSet<string> { "::1" }; //::1 = localhost
        foreach (var ip in Config.RestrictedAccesIps)
        {
            authorizedIPs.Add(ip);
        }
        app.Use(typeof(IpFilterMiddleware), authorizedIPs);

        if (Config.AuthMode == WebApi.GlobalConst.Auth0)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Config.OrganizationId))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Organization Id missing");
            }

            var domain = Config.Domain;
            var apiIdentifier = Config.ApiIdentifier;
            var keyResolver = new OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver(domain);

            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidAudience = apiIdentifier,
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidIssuer = domain,
                        IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, kid, parameters) => keyResolver.GetSigningKey(kid)
                    }
                });
        }

        // Configure the routes and add filters
        var httpConfiguration = WebApiConfig.ConfigureWebApi();

        // Use the extension method provided by the WebApi.Owin library:
        app.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration);
    }

The error I now have is the preflight option call that get rejected with a Http 401 error.

Before you call axios.get, is accessToken actually set?

@AndréLehto Yes the token is set, I can see it in the dev tools.

Ok, it is very hard to help you out here, since there isn't enough information. If you could export and share your postman request as Axios, we could compare what the call looks like in Postman with what you have shared here.

@AndréLehto here the code snippet generated form postman :
const axios = require('axios');
let config = {
method: 'get',
maxBodyLength: Infinity,
url: 'http://localhost:10000/****/Currencies',
headers: {
'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJS....
}
};
axios.request(config)
.then((response) => {
console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch((error) => {
console.log(error);
});

Please do not add code here. Add it as an edit to your Question.

My issue was the proxy, I had to put :
proxy: 'https://localhost:3000'
In the package.json
